# Why is the descriptive quantitative expression coincident with the expression of possession in many languages?

Tags: semantics

One kind of descriptive expression is the description of quantity. Below are some examples of descriptive expression of time:

> English: an hour'**s** journey
>
> Chinese: yixiaoshi **de** lucheng
>
> Japanese: ichijikan **no** michinori
>
> French: voyage **d**'une heure
>
> Icelandic: ein**s** tím**a** ferð

All the parts marked in bold are also the fundamental elements indicating possession in each language, such as "Peter'**s** house".

What is the semantic relevance that makes the two kinds of expression identical? or what are some other factors lead to it?

Comment: Are you certain that the explanation is semantic?

Comment: Possession is the usual default interpretation for noun - noun constructions, as in Hebrew, for instance. When a default marker is used between the nouns, it usually also can be used to signal possession.